# Create Themes for Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

How can I create a theme for all controls on the interface so that you don't have to set style for each control?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you will need to override the default system styles.
You can find more info by reading:

[Theme Forcing for Windows Phone 7 (Silverlight)](http://matthiasshapiro.com/2011/01/17/theme-forcing-for-windows-phone-7-silverlight/)

[How to override theme resources in Windows Phone 7.5](http://blog.johanlaanstra.nl/?p=95)

Also, I recommend checking out the [ThemeManager by Jeff Wilcox](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2012/01/phonethememanager/)